# Most efficient way to remove an item from array?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays. If a user adds a product, we put it in the ProductArray. If they remove that product, we add it to the ProductArrayRemove array as well as remove it from the product array.  (We need to know products that have been added as well as products that have been removed. This requires redundancy.)

```
ProductArray = JSON.parse(ProductArray);
ProductArrayRemove = JSON.parse(ProductArrayRemove);
```

When I add and item to the array, I simply do this:

```
 ProductArray.push(ItemID);
 ProductArrayRemove.push(ItemID);
```

But when I remove it, I have to do this:

```
var len = ProductArray.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ProductID = ProductArray[i];
    if (ProductID == ItemID) {
        ProductArray.splice(i,1);
        break;
    }
}
```

It seems that there should be a better way of accomplishing this task.

Is there a more efficient means of getting rid of a single item (that will always be an integer) from an array?

Comment: `var i = array.length;while(--i){if(array[i]===itemID){array.splice(i,1);break}}` - What's wrong with this?

Comment: If you need access at `O(1)` speeds, you need to use a map instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One different idea that would be super fast to remove an item is to just maintain a single list of items and have a property on each item for whether it is removed or not.

Then to remove an item, all you do it set it's property `obj.removed = true`.

The add it back again, you just change the value of that property.

To iterate just the added items, you just skip the ones with the `.removed == true` property.  To iterate just the removed items, you do just the reverse.  Here would be a couple of iterators:

```
ProductArray.iterateAdded = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (!this[i].removed) {
            if (fn.call(this, i, this[i]) === false) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

ProductArray.iterateRemoved = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].removed) {
            if (fn.call(this, i, this[i]) === false) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

ProductArray.getSubLength = function(removed) {
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (removed == this[i].removed) {
            ++cnt;
        }
    }
    return(cnt);
}
```

And, you would use them like this:

```
ProductArray.iterateAdded(function(i, val) {
   // this is the array
   // i is the index we are iterating
   // val is the array element we are iterating this[i]
   // put code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make your two lists objects instead of arrays of integers, and use `delete` to remove the items:

```
// removing an item
function RemoveProduct(ItemID) {
    delete ProductsAdded[ItemID];
    ProductsRemoved[ItemID] = ItemID;
}

// adding an item
function AddProduct(ItemID) {
    delete ProductsRemoved[ItemID];
    ProductsAdded[ItemID] = ItemID;
}
```

Now, this would require some extra mangling on the server-side, since it should send off a json encoded hash (or map, or assoc array depending on language) instead of a list, but this is definitely a much faster way to remove.

Comment: No! *Never* use delete on an *array*, delete should only be used on object literals, because a delete on array will leave you with an item in the area with the value undefined rather than splice which removes the actual item.

Comment: My solution calls for creating them as object literals instead of arrays, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I use the array syntax to index the objects, but it's still an object, isn't it?

Comment: *genius*, at least you could have renamed it to ProductObject, it didn't occur to me that you meant that ProductArray was meant to be an object literal in your sample code. :P

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about renaming it but I didn't want to change too much of it. I'll make that edit now though to remove confusion.

Answer (score 1):

use the Array method indexOf- it is worth the extra code you need to explain it to old and
undernourished browsers to have it to use in code like yours.

```
var i= ProductArray.indexOf(ProductID);
if(i> -1) ProductArray.splice(i, 1);
```

//This shim is about average:

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf) Array.prototype.indexOf= function(what, i){
    if(!i || typeof i!= 'number') i= 0;
    var L= this.length;
    while(i< L){
        if(this[i]=== what) return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, it is often mistaken that calling function is more efficient than writing 10 lines of code. Most of us don't think what is actually the function is doing and how many lines are there in the function. For e.g: `indexOf` cannot be implemented without using a loop or additional variables.

Here in your case you add an element using `push` which actually appends an element at the end of the array. So it is simple, add one more memory location to the array. But when you remove an element you remove it from any index in the array. So the steps involved are

1. Find the index of the element
2. Remove the element from that index
3. Adjust the index of all elements after the deleted index

Obviously looping is needed and using loop will not make it less efficient. My suggestion is to avoid using `splice` ( as you have already started a loop ) and remove the element using your loop only - do something as shown below

```
var len = ProductArray.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ProductID = ProductArray[i];
    if (ProductID == ItemID && i != len-1) {
        ProductArray[i] = ProductArray[i+1];
        ProductArray[i+1] = ItemID;
    }else if(i == len-1){
        ProductArray.length = i;
    }
}
```

You can make it a function of array by adding it to protoype

```
Array.prototype.removeItem = function (itemID){
    // put the code here replacing "ProductArray" with "this"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be mistaken, but isn't your code simply doing the same as

```
ProductArray.splice(ProductArray.indexOf(ItemID),1);
```

(not tested and written from the top of my head, but that should work as far as I know, though it won't work if you have multiple items with ItemID)

Comment: Don't forget to check whether the return value of `indexOf` is **not** `-1`, or you'll cut off the last element.

Comment: Only if you are unsure of the existence of the index in question which often isn't that much of an issue if you want to delete a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

No. Such an operation has to take linear time to find the element to remove (assuming the items are not ordered in any way) and to move succeeding elements backward. The code can be cleaned though as other answers have suggested.

Comment: Not true, browser *may* optimize the indexOf on an array in various ways which a normal for loop doesn't account for, so using indexOf is more efficient than a custom for loop (even if only for being native, but too tired to make a benchmark).

Comment: Like the increment and condition on i and such? But it does have to traverse the whole list of elements before the desired one right?

Comment: @DavidMulder: it's still going to have to scan the entire array

Comment: http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-for-loop2 (Native stuff always allows for optimizations you can't beat on the javascript level, e.g. memory management or maybe even some form of indexes)

Comment: Btw, just to clarify myself, the "Not true" referred to the "No", which was a direct response to the question whether there is a more efficient way. I idn't mean in any way that there isn't an inherent limit as described by wirate and Juan Mendes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use objects, where the keys are the product ID#s, and the values contain whatever metadata you want (e.g. when the removal occurred, on what webpage, etc.; it could even be arbitrary).

```
var added = {432215: {...}, 432676: {...}};
var removed = {432215: {...}};
```

That would be the most efficient way, as you asked for, if you're willing to modify things around a bit. However your question "What's the most efficient way..." is not that reasonable, since a user is unlikely to have more than maybe 100 items in his cart tops. Even if you had an O(N^2) algorithm you wouldn't see issues until perhaps 1000 items. So just use the method which is easiest to code.

Do note that there is a possible flaw in the design of this system: it is reasonable for the customer to remove an item and add it back later. Depending on what you are keeping track of, you may need to special-case this.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this:

```
var itemId = 6;
var products = [1,3,5,6,7];
var removedProducts = new Array();
removedProducts.push(
   products.splice(products.indexOf(itemId), 1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort is probably surprisingly well optimized in most browsers. Pop is also typically very fast since the concept of stacks begins in assembly. Being able to define sort functions is really powerful. Mostly though I get the impression you'd like it a touch more easy to use which I think this is.

```
Array.prototype.numFindPop = function(id){
    this.sort( 
        function(a,b){
            if(a === id){ return -1; }//keeps moving id to the right when found
        }
    );

    return this.pop();

}
```

So in your case:

```
//remove
ProductArrayRemove.push(
    ProductArray.numFindPop(35)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter()` should do the trick. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`Array.filter()` goes through each array element (this case `product`) and returns a new modified array based on your needs (this case, returns an array without the deleted product)

It would look like something like this:

```
  ProductArray = ProductArray.filter(function(product) {
        return product !== ItemID
    })
```

the `product` is each array element in your ProductArray.

You even make it smaller with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is almost the same `function()` but more compact and limited.

```
  ProductArray = ProductArray.filter(product => product !== ItemID)
```

Now the ProductArray doesn't have the deleted product and it's a one-liner solution